# Reshape a jq array with summarized data

Tags: json, dictionary, group-by, jq, reshape

New to jq but I've managed to group a load of data which I would now like summarized in a different format. Original data after group by and mapping:

```
[
  {
    "Agents": "a",
    "Count": 1
  },
  {
    "Agents": "b",
    "Count": 50
  },
  {
    "Agents": "c",
    "Count": 25
  },
  {
    "Agents": "d",
    "Count": 1
  },
  {
    "Agents": "e",
    "Count": 4
  },
  {
    "Agents": "f",
    "Count": 4
  },
  {
    "Agents": "g",
    "Count": 4
  }
]
```

and I would like this output:

```
{
  "Count": 7,
  "Agents": {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 50,
    "c": 25,
    "d": 1,
    "e": 4,
    "f": 4,
    "g": 4
  }
}
```

How exactly might I do this in jq please because it requires mapping the values as field names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another variant using `reduce` would be to do. The reduce expression takes the array as input and puts the key as the `Agents` and the value as its corresponding `Count` value.

```
jq '{ Count: length, Agents: (reduce .[] as $d ({}; .[$d.Agents] = $d.Count)) }'
```

The Object Value Iterator `.[]` used to construct the JSON. For a given `.["a"]`, it returns `"a"` which is how the keys are constructed in the final JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Use `map` to create an input for `from_entries`:

```
map({key: .Agents, value: .Count}) | {Count: length, Agents: from_entries}
```

`map` produces a list of objects like `[{"key": "a", "value": 1}, ...]`. `from_entries` turns that into a single object `{"a": 1, ...}`. In the final object, both `length` and `from_entries` get the same array as input, and their outputs are used to create the final object with `Count` and `Agents` keys.